# Jenkinsfile : java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have Jenkins Pipeline code in jenkisnfile which is 790 lines. I am getting following error message `Method code too large`

```
11:05:24  org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
11:05:24  General error during class generation: Method code too large!
11:05:24  
11:05:24  java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
11:05:24    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.MethodWriter.a(Unknown Source)
11:05:24    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source)
11:05:24    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$17.call(CompilationUnit.java:827)
11:05:24    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
11:05:24    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
11:05:24    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
11:05:24    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
11:05:24    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
11:05:24    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
11:05:24    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
11:05:24    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
11:05:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
11:05:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
11:05:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:571)
11:05:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:523)
11:05:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
11:05:24    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
11:05:24    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
11:05:24  
11:05:24  1 error
11:05:24  
11:05:24    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
11:05:24    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
11:05:24    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
11:05:24    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
11:05:24    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
11:05:24    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
11:05:24    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
11:05:24    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
11:05:24    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
11:05:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
11:05:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
11:05:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:571)
11:05:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:523)
11:05:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
11:05:24    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
11:05:24    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
11:05:24  Finished: FAILURE
```

Using following versions
OS : `Ubuntu 18.04.1`
Jenkins : `2.263.4`
Java : `1.8.0_181` ( Master & Slave )
Set `JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx2048m"` in `/etc/default/jenkins`( Master )

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java has a 64K size limit on bytecode. It is not an issue with Jenkins. To solve this, you should break apart your pipeline into methods. There is a great example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40049949/15678539).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a limitation and you must use shared libraries/ divide them into methods to fix this.
Reference for shared libraries:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

**Solution:** Use your jenkinsfile for defining stages and all methods/functionalities are implemented in shared library which will just be called from your jenkinsfile.

Example implemenation as shown below.
Create a file named : sharedlibraries (groovy file)

```
#!groovy
// Write or add Functions(definitions of stages) which will be called from your jenkins file
def Create_AMI(PROJECT_NAME, ENV_NAME)
 {
     echo ENV_NAME
     sh "packer build jenkins/${PROJECT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}-ami.json"
     // You can also set the environment below example:
     env.ENV_NAME ="dev"
 }

return this
```

In your Jenkinsfile write below code:

```
// Global variable is used to get data from groovy file(shared library)
def stagelibrary
stage('Create New AMI') {   
            steps {
              script {
                        // Load Shared library Groovy file stagelibraries.Give your path of stagelibraries file whic is created
                        stagelibrary = load 'C:\\Jenkins\\stagelibraries'
                        // Execute Create_AMI function. You can add if else conditions over here, based on your branches. But am not sure of your conditions.
                        // You can also pass your environment variable 
                        // in the Crete_AMI function using env.<YOURENVVARIABLE>
                        stagelibrary.Create_AMI(PROJECT_NAME,env.ENV_NAME)       
                      }               
                  }
        }
```

This was just an example to show you how you can divide your functionality into sharedlibraries and which will not give you error related to code limit.