# Two Arrays in a single definition in Groovy

Tags: arrays, jenkins, groovy

I have to pass two different parameters from my Jenkin job, to my groovy function . I am trying to read them in two different arrays as shown below. But somehow, it is not working. its working, if I pass only one parameter to one array.

Parameter 1 = imagelist1

parameter 2 = imagelist2

```
def abc = {
  container('xyz') {

    String[] arrspt = imagelist1.split(' ')
    for(int i=0; i < arrspt.length; i++) {
      env.image_name = arrspt[i] 
      sh 'echo "${image_name}" >> images_to_scan.txt' 
    }
    
    String[] arrStr = imagelist2.split(' ')
    for(int i=0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
       env.image_name2 =  arrStr[i]
       sh 'echo "${image_name2}" >> images_to_scan.txt
    }
  }
}
```

when I run the Jenkin Job, I am getting error as below :

> [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
>
> [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException:
> startup failed:
>
> General error during class generation: Method too large:
> Pipeline.___cps___19086323
> ()Lcom/cloudbees/groovy/cps/impl/CpsFunction;
>
> groovyjarjarasm.asm.MethodTooLargeException: Method too large:
> Pipeline.___cps___19086323
> ()Lcom/cloudbees/groovy/cps/impl/CpsFunction;`

Am I doing something wrong in declaring the 2 different arrays in Groovy?

Any help here is highly appreciated !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67303181/jenkinsfile-java-lang-runtimeexception-method-code-too-large

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is coming from this part of the code ? The error seems to say that your whole file if too big. Try refactoring it into functions.
Another piece of advice, you can sum the both `.split(' ')` into once since array, then loop only once. Also, check groovy's `.each{ }` and `collect{}`, and jenkins `writeFile()`. 
You'll be able to reduce a lot of code with those ;)
Welcome do SO ;)