# Jenkins Method too large

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

After modifying Jenkinfiles slightly, by adding 1 more environment variables to

```
environment{



...

uuid = <256 char long uuid>

}
```

I  get error:

```
7:37:34  Library piper-lib-os@v1.221.0 is cached. Copying from home.
17:37:35  org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
17:37:35  General error during class generation: Method too large: WorkflowScript.___cps___18504794 ()Lcom/cloudbees/groovy/cps/impl/CpsFunction;
17:37:35  
17:37:35  groovyjarjarasm.asm.MethodTooLargeException: Method too large: WorkflowScript.___cps___18504794 ()Lcom/cloudbees/groovy/cps/impl/CpsFunction;
```

I've searched for this, but cannot find any issue, as the only change is adding environment variable

Answer (score 2):

Java has a  64K size limit on bytecode. This is count in the `pipeline`  block, therefore, environment is included there.

You might need to break your pipeline into method as stated in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049917/jenkins-pipeline-script-fails-with-general-error-during-class-generation-metho/40049949#40049949)

For environment you can create a custom method that returns the value you need:

```
pipeline { 
 environment { ...
   MYENV = getEnvUUID()
   ...
 }
...
}


def getEnvUUID() {
  return 'really-long-uuid'
}
```